# can not set expire time with `SET` in redis

Tags: redis, set

```
\# redis-server -v
Redis server v=3.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=efd64775fb9b8d51
\# redis-cli -v
redis-cli 3.0.5

\# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo 10 10
(error) ERR syntax error
```

http://redis.io/commands/set

> SET key value [EX seconds] [PX milliseconds] [NX|XX] Starting with
>   Redis 2.6.12 SET supports a set of options that modify its behavior:

why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo 10 ex 10
OK
```

very impressed

Comment: @IKavanagh This seems to be an answer. You can see in the upper right corner of the review page that this question has no other answers so there is nobody to "thank". Please be more careful during review.